# sum calculation

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I would like to calculate, or bound from above, the following sum
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(n-2i)^p{p \choose i}, 
$$
here $p\geq 2$.

Any references are very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, it is not bigger than $(2 n)^p$

Comment: I would like to get something sharper :-)
The idea to compute it: split sum into 'pieces' like $n/2-c\sqrt n\leq i\leq n/2+c \sqrt n$.

Comment: I assume that you mean ${p \choose i}=0$ when $n>p$ correct?

Comment: $p$ fixed, $n\to\infty$? $n$ fixed, $p\to\infty$? $n,p$ both going to infinity in some unspecified way?

Comment: I'm betting Michael intended to write $\binom{n}{i}$ so that this is the $2^{n+p}$ times the $p$-th central moment of the binomial distribution $Bin(n,1/2)$.

Comment: It is supposed to be a comment, but button "comment'' does not appear on my screen. Please turn this 'answer' into a 'comment'. Yes, $n$ is fixed and $p$ goes to $\infty$. In the P. Laplace, Théorie analytique des probabilités, Paris, 1812, can be found the formula:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^j{n \choose j}(n-2j)^n=2^{n-1}n!$$ Can we now say something about $\sum_{i=0}^n(2i-n)^p{p \choose i}$?

Comment: I think the usual protocol here is to edit your own question,
not to comment on it.  Anyway, if you fix $n>0$ and let $p \rightarrow \infty$
then each factor $p \choose i$ is $O(p^n)$ while $(2i-n)^p$ depends
exponentially on $n$, so the dominant terms are those with $i=n$ and $i=0$,
giving an asymptotic of
$\bigl( {p \choose n} + (-1)^p \bigr) n^p + O(p^{n-1} (n-2)^p)$.

Comment: Thank you. But what will happend if both $n$ and $p$ goes to $\infty$, thinking that $n$ goes to $\infty$ faster then $p$ does?

Comment: The paper http://info.tuwien.ac.at/panholzer/Papers/P13.pdf has some results that seem quite similar, so perhaps the methods used there can be adapted to Michael's problem. 

Comment: @Richard Stanley: thank you very much

Comment: Michael = David?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Dear Gerry Mayerson, I have to admit that its a cross-post. And I have been already punished for cross posts.  I am very sorry. And It would not happened again!

Comment: But why crosspost under different names? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed this is not simple. Maybe a little information on the background of this problem?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but it can be shown that all the zeros of the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^p (x-2i)^p{p\choose i}$ have real part $p$.

Answer (score 1):

On of methods for finding an approximation or bound for a finite sum is  using the following formula
$$
\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) \sim \int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \,\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k - 1)'}(b) - f^{(2k - 1)'}(a)\right)$$
and by taking $f(i)= (n-2i)^p\binom {p}{i}$
you can consider decimal digits of right hand side which are faster than of left hand side. Also $B_k$ here are Bernoulli numbers.

Moreover, the sharp bounds of Bernoulli numbers has been computed ,(see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%252Fs000130050432#page-1) )
So you can also try to find a bound for your sum.